# SPA + Backend + Office365 SSO

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

I am building an application consisting of the following

1. SPA (Provides a front end for the user to perform actions) - app.myservice.com - React JS
2. API (Provides the core business logic and is called by the SPA) - api.myservice.com - Node JS

***What I would like to do is allow people to "Signup" to my application (as a whole) using Office 365.***

However.... I want the API to generate JWT tokens which the SPA will use to communicate with the API in the future. I do not want the SPA to have Office365 specific tokens.

The process would look like this at a high level:

1. User goes to app.myservice.com
2. User clicks "Signup"
3. User is redirected to Office365 to provide login details
4. Office365 redirects to my API
5. API creates a local user in its database
6. API generates a JWT
7. API returns JWT to SPA
8. SPA calls API using JWT to perform actions.

What is unclear to me, is what OAuth2/OpenID flow type to use in order to achieve this.

Further this, I would like to understand if my approach has any flaws in general.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In step 3 above, I think your SPA should redirect to Azure AD, which is where the user signs in. Your SPA will then receive an Azure AD token and can send it to the API. The API can potentially read user info and create a user if required. APIs should not issue their own tokens or receive redirects. Not sure if this will 100% meet your requirements but it is the standard pattern for the 3 legged SPA and API OAuth 2.0 based dance.

Comment: Thanks Gary. 

I have started adopting the approach you outlined. 

However, I would like to understand more about your statement

**APIs should not issue their own tokens or receive redirects**

Does this mean, the API would need to handle tokens generated from all SSO providers (Azure, Facebook, Google and its own local database) ?

Would it **not** make sense to have a single token which is generated by the API which abstracts away the underlying provider (Considering, the user is ultimately logging in and linked to a user which exists in the APIs Database) ?

Thanks